# Google cloud SDK stalls without error message

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am trying to learn how to use Google Appengine with python, using PyCharm Pro as trial. In have installed the Cloud SDK and it is active as indicated by getting access to both admin page and the Hello World! page. I had to overcome cannot bind problem by changing the port using dev_appserver.py

After that when I try to run the app in python, I get the following lines

```
    INFO     2017-05-16 03:23:13,314 sdk_update_checker.py:231] Checking for updates to the SDK.
    INFO     2017-05-16 03:23:13,458 sdk_update_checker.py:259] The SDK is up to date.
    INFO     2017-05-16 03:23:13,517 api_server.py:272] Starting API server at: http://localhost:51009
    INFO     2017-05-16 03:23:13,520 dispatcher.py:205] Starting module "default" running at: http://127.0.0.1:9000
    INFO     2017-05-16 03:23:13,522 admin_server.py:116] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
```

and it stalls there, nothing else happens and I get no error messages. I tried taking all the code out of the app.py file and just put a simple print('hello') and still does the same. tried restarting and reinitializing the Cloud SDK as well as the whole computer and still the same.

I am using MacOS and python venv as interpreter with webapp2 installed.

I looked in this forum and in multiple others and didn't see this problem described any where.

Also worth mentioning that the firewall is off

Comment: That's pretty normal (at least on linux) until you get actual traffic to your module(s). Is anything else happening if you access http://127.0.0.1:9000 in your browser?